# How to isolate X in this eqquation?

Tags: functions

How to isolate $x$ in this equation: $px+(\frac{b}{a})px=m$

> Blockquote

And get $\frac{a}{a+b}*\frac{m}{p}$

Comment: First, factor out the "$x$" from the LHS.

Answer (score 2):

$$px+\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)px=m$$
$$\left(1+\frac{b}{a}\right)px=m$$
$$px=\frac{m}{1+\frac{b}{a}}=\frac{am}{a+b}$$
$$x=\frac{am}{p(a+b)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $p$ and $x$ are two common factors of the two terms of the sum so we can factor:
$$px+\frac b a px=p\left(1+\frac b a\right)x=p\frac{a+b}ax$$
Can you take it from here?